# How to handle Express errors without relying on the function's length property?

Tags: javascript, express

From Express's [error handling docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html):

> Define error-handling middleware functions in the same way as other middleware functions, except error-handling functions have four arguments instead of three: `(err, req, res, next)`. For example:
>
> ```
> app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
>   console.error(err.stack)
>   res.status(500).send('Something broke!')
> })
> ```

It seems that Express's `.use(middlware)` inspects the middleware function's `length` to see how many arguments it takes, and if four, then it treats it differently to other middleware functions, passing it an error as the first argument.

This is incompatible with modern linting setups like XO or Airbnb, as it forces you to define an extra trailing parameter tha [doesn't get consumed](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars) (i.e. `next` in the above example). Also, unused trailing parameters might get removed by some automated code transformations, which is just something I don't want to worry about. In my opinion, `Function.prototype.length` is best kept for metaprogramming/introspection as opposed to affecting real production behaviour.

Is there any other, more explicit way to define an error handler in Express, that doesn't force you to *imply* intended functionality through the number of parameters your function takes?

Comment: If you read [this](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html#the-default-error-handler), it's suggested that custom error handlers should delegate to the built-in error handler (using `next`) when response headers have already been sent to the client. In which case, `next` won't be unused. But I understand your issue. However, I don't think there's a more explicit method of adding a custom error handler in Express.